# Regex did not match, but why?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have to following regex:

```
(\/\*\*)([\s[:graph:]]*@brief[\s[:graph:]]*\r)( \*\/)
```

and I'm trying to check for the following:

```
/**
    @brief TestViewController

    <##full description#>

    @see UIViewController
    @ingroup <##group/module#>

    @date 2012-10-29
 */
@interface LaunchViewController : UIViewController {
```

which is in code variable.

It will not match, checking this way:

```
if @code =~ /(/*\*)([\s[:graph:]]*@brief[\s[:graph:]]*\r)( \*\)/
    puts "found----------" 
end
```

and I also tried it that way:

```
r = Regexp.new(Regexp.quote('/') + Regexp.quote('**') + '[\s[:graph:]]*@brief[\s[:graph:]]*\r ' + Regexp.quote('*/'))
```

Can anyone help me please fixing this?

In this case I'm not interested in groups so please do not wonder about the one having groups and the other one with none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby doesn't usually include `\r` in linebreaks. If you change the regexp to:

```
/(\/\*\*)([\s[:graph:]]*@brief[\s[:graph:]]*)( \*\/)/
```

I get a match.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this, thanks. Would you use \n instead? Oh wait, I'll test this, too and reply :)

Comment: ok, I have tried both, no \r -> working,  \n instead of \r -> also working - Thanks a lot! Saved my day ;)